# Mute/unmute IK via Python API

Tags: python, bones, constraints

I'm trying to mute/unmute an IK constraint via Python, but unfortunately the change is not applied.

```
def update_function(group, context):
    pose = bpy.data.objects["Armature"].pose
    pose.bones["Gripper Core Bone"].constraints["IK"].mute = not group.enable_ik
    context.scene.update()
```

Any ideas what's happening? The "eye" icon in the properties menu does update.

I'm using the Blender 2.80 beta.